# Is this a contraction mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces, banach-fixed-point

This is an exercise to show that completeness is essential for the fixed point property of a contraction mapping

Consider $X=\{P(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N a_nx^n,a_n\in \mathbb{R}\}$ the real-coefficient polynomials of degree less than $N$ and the norm $||P||=max\{|a_n|\}$.

The problem claims that the mapping $$T:p(x)\longrightarrow (1+x)p(x)$$ is a contraction but i can't see why since for $$p(x)=x^2+x,q(x)=x^2$$ we have
$$||T(p-q)||=||x^2+x||=||p-q||=||x||$$.

any hints would be great.

Comment: Indeed $||T||=1$

Comment: What about $p=1+x,$ $q=0?$ We have $T(p-q)=1+2x+x^2.$